# c++ weird string size

Tags: c++, string

I encountered a weird string size problem. Here is my sample code

**sampleA**

```
std::string getexepath()
{
    char result[ PATH_MAX ];
    int found;
    ssize_t count = readlink( "/proc/self/exe", result, PATH_MAX );
    found = std::string(result).find_last_of("/");
    std::string pp = std::string(result).substr(found+1);
    std::string kk = std::string(result).substr(found+1);
    std::cout << kk << kk.size() << std::endl;
    return kk;
}
```

**sampleB**

```
std::string getexepath()
{
    char result[ PATH_MAX ];
    int found;
    ssize_t count = readlink( "/proc/self/exe", result, PATH_MAX );
    found = std::string(result).find_last_of("/");
    //std::string pp = std::string(result).substr(found+1);
    std::string kk = std::string(result).substr(found+1);
    std::cout << kk << kk.size() << std::endl;
    return kk;
}
```

The outputs are different; the sampleB output is 2 char more than sampleA. I guess the difference is `'\0'`; sampleB output is including `'\0'` and sampleA isn't.

I am wondering what causes the problem. 
after review the answer, now I know i missed '\0'. but i still want to know why added this statement "std::string pp = std::string(result).substr(found+1)" will cause a difference result.

Thanks

Comment: The documentation for [`readlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) states : "readlink() does not append a null byte to buf." So I'm curious. Doesn't it make sense to  heed that described functionality and set `result[count] = 0;` *before* using it to construct a `std::string` ? (assuming you actually check the result for not being (-1), which you're currently *not* doing).

Comment: Does the text `sampleA` and `sampleB` literally appear in your code?

Comment: Wouldn't you actually want to set `result[count]`, and make the buffer 1 char bigger?

Comment: @user2357112 absolutely. thanks for the sharp eye.

Comment: after I added result[count]='\0', kk.size() give me the same as before. it does't increase the size of "kk" string. why?

Answer (score 2):

You guess is right. The problem is that you forgot to set `result[count]=0` . Therefore your code has undefined behavior because the char array `result` is not terminated by '\0'.

After you add

```
    result[count] = 0;
```

before `found = ...`, you will get the same results for both sample A and sample B.

Comment: You are right. after added result[count] = '\0' , SampleA and B have the same output. but i am still wondering why this statement "std::string pp = std::string(result).substr(found+1)" always make A and B difference?

Comment: I believe that behavior is implementation dependent because I run it with gcc 4.4.5 it gives different size but with Solaris CC it gives the same size.

Answer (score 1):

The memory of `result[ PATH_MAX ]` on the stack is not initialized, so the content of result is uncertained. Like the comment of WhozCraig:

> readlink() does not append a null byte to buf.

So the '\0' may appear in every place after `result[ count-1 ]`, and the output in your code is undefined. When declare a C format string, we'd better initialize the string like this: `char result[ PATH_MAX ] = {0};`. Hope these can help you.